# Hugo SSG use numbers instead of dates to rank posts

Tags: hugo, static-site-generation

very dumb/random question but is there a way to just use numbers instead of dates to rank posts?

For example what if I want to build an outline in my post listing

- 1.0
- 1.1
- 1.11
- 1.111

Instead of the normal rank desc date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are listing out your posts.
You can sort:
https://gohugo.io/functions/sort/
So, a front matter param like:
(Pseudo code here)

```
post_index: 1.0
```

Then in the template/layout:

```
{{ range sort .Params.post_index "value" "desc" }}{{ . }} {{ end }}
```

Your reference is here: https://gohugo.io/functions/sort/

(there are a few ways to do this - so this should at least get you started)

Comment: Oh ok cool, so I'd just use that param and not include a date param in the list? Duh, I guess that's obvious. Thanks so much!